# Blog post invites people to apply to become CEO of Stack Exchange, Inc., but doesn't indicate how to apply

Tags: support, jobs, blog

Having just seen [the blog post about Joel stepping down as CEO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/03/28/the-next-ceo-of-stack-overflow/), I am (of course) immediately wondering how to apply.

In his haste to publish the news, he seems to have left of that vital bit of information. I was fully expecting there to be a link to [an ad in jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs). The [company work here page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) also doesn't list it as an available position to apply for.

Since I am, of course, *eminently* qualified, I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of the application form.

Comment: @Sonic Your edit is a bit misleading. The blog post does not actually even use the word "apply" anywhere, only that we're looking for candidates. It does also state this: "We will, no doubt, hire one of those fancy executive headhunters to help us in the search." But a clarification on where to go to be considered would be useful assuming there is a place to go already.

Comment: @animuson It doesn't use the word "apply", but it does very strongly imply that the reader is being invited to apply for the job.

Comment: This is one of those "if you need to ask..." things.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog "We're looking for a CEO" does not imply they are searching for the person among Stack Exchange users. It's like someone at work saying they're looking for a reliable plumber or landscape  gardener. It's just an announcement.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being voted for closure as blatantly off-topic. It's about the blog post; since when did discussing about blog posts or SE Inc. the company become blatantly off-topic?

Comment: `Blog post invites people to apply to become CEO of Stack Exchange, Inc.,` No, it absolutely  doesn't. If it were true there would be a link to an application form.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, it does strongly imply that people should apply. "*We're looking for a new CEO […] so we decided to put this announcement out there in hopes of finding great candidates that might have been under the radar.*"

Comment: @TomWright I reverted your edit. It detracts from your question and based on patterns I've seen in prior questions, it can actually make your argument weaker and result in downvotes. Italics are enough to imply sarcasm.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ, Tom Wright's post is dripping with sarcasm and joking over the top self aggrandizing. By your name, I am going to assume that English is not your first language and I understand how subtle things like sarcasm are insanely hard to pick up between languages. But just so you know, it is very clear that Tom doesn't think this highly of himself, he is joking.

Comment: @Asyranok As an aside, ironically πάντα-ῥεῖ's name is not related to his country of origin (though indeed English is not his first language), which may or may not serve as a reminder not to make assumptions ;) "Asyranok" isn't an English name, either.

Comment: For CEO positions, you don't apply, you get headhunted.

Comment: @Magisch I have seen some CEO job positions posted online.... but usually for smaller companies :)

Comment: There isn't an application form because Jon Skeet won JIT.

Answer (score 44):

One of the skills expected from a CEO is initiative. The person who applies for the position is expected to know how to contact Stack Exchange and present themselves in the proper way.

That's why, to my understanding, Stack Exchange didn't post a direct form, which would have only led to hundreds of joke/unsuitable submissions, and just wasted SE staff's time by wading through it all.

So yes, they're looking for a new CEO. They want only the best of the best to apply. Good luck! :)

Comment: plus there is diversity statement, they look for someone who can enrich their vaues, that is why I think they will use headhunters

Answer (score 32):

To quote [Mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/268944/mark) [in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325874/blog-post-invites-people-to-apply-to-become-ceo-of-stack-exchange-inc-but-doe/326026#comment1063781_325874):

> This is one of those "if you need to ask..." things.

You don't apply to be the CEO of a company via an online form on a blog post.

Anyone looking to "get in" that way is not going to be qualified for the role. (Witness, if you will, 21 year olds in the blog comments submitting their name with great confidence…)

That's why there's no such thing.

The usual methodologies will, I'm sure, be utilitised to seek out the next Executive of the organisation. If you are familiar with those methodologies from your previous experience in business directorship, you will know how best to make known your interest for the role. If you are not, this is likely not the role for you.

Good luck!

(As an aside: when I'm made CEO next month, this 1st April CSS will be permanent. Just sayin'.)

Answer (score 17):

He didn't leave out the information, but he hid it. You clearly need to come to Venetian Hotel to the main ballroom (but Shhh don't tell anybody that's the part of the test). There are a lot of other bits of information to help you there I'll give you the obvious ones. You also clearly need to bring an ISO file.

> I thought it would be a fun thing to ask the developers in the room
>   how many of them had visited Stack Overflow

(Just look at the capitalized letters).

It also needs to be on either USB or re-writable CD/DVD that's what the TMP means in (so that the ISO file is temporary).

> It is great to watch Trello (under Michael Pryor)